# Calling sinatra halt from inside a module?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app and would like to use the halt method from inside a custom module. When I try to call halt from inside of the custom module I receive an error saying "undefined method `halt' for Standup:Module". How do I make Sinatra methods visible inside another module?

Comment: If you show a bit of code then it'll be easier to see why it's not working.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue - did you ever solve this?

Comment: Were you calling `halt` inside a `configure` block, instead of inside a route method? I have an app set up in modular format, and I was getting the same error, before realizing that `halt` is a route-related method.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I thought I'd post for the good of others:

So, I just saw a cool module provided in Sinatra's contrib called Sinatra::Extension. Without any code from you, we're shooting in the dark, but this at least sounds promising for your use-case. http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/extension.html